# Compiler error with calling Generic methods java

Tags: java, generics

I have created a generic class with few methods. I just want to call the method and add value but its not working. Here is the code

```
public interface GenericInterface<T> {
    public T getValue();
    public  void setValue(T t);
}

public class FirstGeneric<T> implements GenericInterface<T> {
    private T value;

    public FirstGeneric(T _value) {
        this.value = _value;
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(T t) {
        this.value = t;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T addValues(FirstGeneric<T> myGeneric, FirstGeneric<T> myGeneric1) {
        T result = null;
        if (myGeneric != null && myGeneric1 != null) {
            T t1 = myGeneric.getValue();
            T t2 = myGeneric1.getValue();
            result = (T) t1.toString().concat(t2.toString());
            System.out.println("Result is:=" + result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer int1 = 1;
        FirstGeneric<Integer> myInt = new FirstGeneric<Integer>(int1);
        String value = "Hello";
        FirstGeneric<String> myString = new FirstGeneric<String>(value);
        addValues(myString,  myInt);
    }
}
```

But i am getting compilation error at last line.

The method addValues(FirstGeneric, FirstGeneric) in the type FirstGeneric is not applicable for the arguments (FirstGeneric, FirstGeneric)

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addValues` has a single generic type parameter, which means you can't pass to it both a `FirstGeneric<Integer>` and a `FirstGeneric<String>`.

To make the `addValues(myString,  myInt)` call valid, you can define two generic type parameters in your method:

```
public static <T,U> String addValues(FirstGeneric<T> myGeneric, FirstGeneric<U> 
   myGeneric1) {
    String result = null;
    if (myGeneric != null && myGeneric1 != null) {
        T t1 = myGeneric.getValue();
        U t2 = myGeneric1.getValue();
        result = t1.toString().concat(t2.toString());
        System.out.println("Result is:=" + result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that I changed the return type to `String`, since it's clearly a `String` (produced by `t1.toString().concat(t2.toString())`), so you can't cast it to `T` and hope that `T` would be a `String`.